# AngularJS Custom Directive Accessing Scope Data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive

We are brand new to AngularJS but are trying to display some html tooltips from a custom directive in Angular and since new new to this technology are struggling to come up with a proper solution to this issue.

We had a version of a solution running using Angular+Web API, but discovered the mouseover events and CRUD functionality belonged in directives instead of the controller, so we're pulling that out and re-building.

Currently in a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fFitR3BQZ8T1NBbFoNJ0?p=preview) POC, we have:

1. Loaded a very small SVG file.
2. Loaded a small json data file.
3. For each SVG  element, attached a custom directive hover event
4. When a particular  element is hovered, an alert() executes with the  element id.

SVG Sample:

```
<g id="f3s362c16">
<rect x="577.5" y="533.2" fill="none" width="22.2" height="25.7"/>
<polyline fill="none" stroke="#CEDEED" stroke-width="0.6468" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="590.4,559 577.5,559 577.5,533.2 
    599.5,533.2 599.5,550   "/>
<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 590.9561 557.4941)" font-family="arial, sans-serif" font-size="5.1408">362.16</text>
```

Json sample:

```
{"Id":1,"empNum":null,"fName":" Bun E.","lName":"Carlos","refacName":null,"deptId":"Drums","divisionId":null,"jobDesc":"Drummer","seatTypeId":1,"officeCode":null,"phone":null,"seatId":"f3s362c12 ","oldSeatId":null,"floor":3,"section":"313 ","seat":"12 "}
```

we have a scope variable for the json defined in the html file:

```
{{ **empData** }}
```

Controller file data load:

```
 var onLoadComplete = function (response) {
   $scope.**empData** = response.data;
 }

 //error
 var onError = function(reason) {
   $scope.error = "Could not get the data";
 }

 //get data
 $http.get('data.json')
    .then(onLoadComplete, onError);
```

Directive to load SVG and add directive to cube element

```
//directive loads SVG into DOM
angular.module('FFPA').directive('svgFloorplan', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',

    templateUrl: 'test.svg',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var groups = element[0].querySelectorAll("g[id^='f3']")
        angular.forEach(groups, function (g,key) {
            var cubeElement = angular.element(g);
            //Wrap the cube DOM element as an Angular jqLite element.
            cubeElement.attr("cubehvr", "");
            $compile(cubeElement)(scope);
        })
      }
    }
}]);
```

Cube Hover Directive:

```
angular.module("FFPA").directive('cubehvr', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    empData: "=",

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //id of group 
        scope.elementId = element.attr("id");

        //function call from line 63
        scope.cubeHover = function () {

            //groupId is the id of the element hovered over.
            var groupId = scope.elementId;

            alert(scope.elementId);
            //Here need to get access to scope empdata json to filter and 
            //match to the cube #.
            //IE: If I hover over 362.12, return json data for
            //{"Id":1,"empNum":null,"fName":" Bun E.","lName":"Carlos","refacName":null,"deptId":"Drums","divisionId":null,"jobDesc":"Drummer","seatTypeId":1,"officeCode":null,"phone":null,"seatId":"f3s362c12 ","oldSeatId":null,"floor":3,"section":"313 ","seat":"12 "}
            //since we don't have access to the empData scope variable, cannot run filter.
            var thisData = empData.filter(function (d) {
              return d.seatId.trim() === groupId
            });
            //after we get a match, we need to display a tooltip with save/cancel buttons.


        };
        element.attr("ng-mouseover", "cubeHover()");
        element.removeAttr("cubehvr");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
}
}]);
```

We are getting the alert for the specific cube hover, but I think we need to get access to the page scope variable to do the filter:

```
var thisData = empData.filter(function (d) {
              return d.seatId.trim() === groupId
```

});

Once we get a match, I think we should be able to append html to our div tag and display it:

```
   <div class="tooltip"></div>
```

Angular:

```
tooltip.html("Name: " + thisData[0].fName + " " + 
thisData[0].lName  + "<br>Role: " + 
thisData[0].jobDesc + "<br>Extension: " + 
thisData[0].phone)//+ "<br>Avatar: <img src=" + thisData[0].Avatar + ">")
.style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 15) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 0) + "px")
.style("visibility", "visible");
```

At this point, we're not sure how to get the view/page scope variable {{empData}} in the hover (2nd) directive since we're already passing cubeHvr the directive:

```
angular.module("FFPA").directive('cubehvr', ['$compile', function ($compile)       {...}
```

Thanks in advance for any direction you might give us here.

Comment: I think the easiest way might be to have a service holding empData. Then any other service/component/directive/controller can inject the service and read the latest results.

Comment: Do you know of an example that we might be able to follow?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a service as the following code

```
angular.module('FFPA')
.service('dataService', function () {
    this.getData = function(){
        return $http.get('data.json').then(function(){
             return response.data;
           }, function(){
               return {err:"Could not get the data"};
           }
        );
    }
});
```

and then inject it to any directive, controller, component or service.

```
angular.module("FFPA").directive('cubehvr', ['$compile','dataService', function ($compile,dataService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        dataService.getData().then(function(data){
            scope.emData=data;
        })
```

Comment: Thanks..

Needed to add $http to the service function parameter.

Question:  Since I am now getting the data each time a user hovers over a cube element, do you recommend not getting the data in for all cubes and simply pass a parameter to the web api and get it for each employee on a hover event?

Thanks again for your help..

Comment: Hi @jazzBox , why not if they won't change .

Comment: One additional question please:  

In the Plunk, we now have  a service that gets the data and 2 directives (1 to load SVG.  1 to handle a SVG <g> element  hover).  Now we have a JS alert that displays the persons name associated to the cube that was hovered over, but need to display a tooltip, which I was thinking of using a page <div>{{emp.name, etc.}}</div> for.  If you don't mind, can you tell us the best way to display the hovered data to say a page $scope variable?

Comment: you could use services to get or share data among controllers and directives and services , but also you could use `rootScope` if services aren't easy for now.

Comment: Although completely new to Angular, I keep thinking that the hover event that gets the cube data should be called from the controller and set the scope employee data there instead of on the directive...

Comment: components are a kind of directives and directives could have controller too.